# How to add and use an import in a script?

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

In the following code I need to add my assembly so that the script can make use of its classes:

```
var options = ScriptOptions.Default.AddImports("MyAssembly");

var code = "using MyAssembly.MyNamespace;" +
           "public class TestClass {" +
           "  public int HelloWorld(int num) {" +
           "    return 5 + num;" +
           "  }" +
           "}";
```

But the following exception is thrown:

> Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.CompilationErrorException' in Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.dll
>   Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.CompilationErrorException: error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MyAssembly' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I added the assembly in the host project too. I've also tried the examples from [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples#addref) but they didn't work either.

What is the correct syntax to add an assembly?

Comment: I was previously trying `.WithImports(new string[] { "namespace.Whatever" });` with no luck. Now working with the `.AddReferences(typeof(namespace.Whatever).Assembly)` Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

The following snippet does the trick:

```
var path = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyAssembly.SomeClass)).Location;
var asm = AssemblyMetadata.CreateFromFile(path).GetReference();

var options = ScriptOptions.Default.AddReferences(asm);
```

This following works too and it uses Linq to get the loaded assembly:

```
var asm = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SingleOrDefault(assembly => assembly.GetName().Name == "MyAssembly");
```

This however gets the loaded assemblies. If the assembly you need is not already loaded, get them using `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies()`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler way to achieve this:

```
ScriptOptions.Default.AddReferences(typeof(MyNamespace.MyAssembly).Assembly);
```