# How can I reference external project DLL with ScriptOptions?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-assembly

I have a project A in which I am writing code to be compiled internally using C# Script objects.

I have created another project in a different solution (external project), project B. I have already added a reference to the ProjectB.DLL inside Project A in the "references" list. What I want is to add Project B's reference on the internal Script code that I want to compile. To better explain, my code is as follows:

My "using statements" are:

```
        APPROVED_USING_STATEMENTS = new HashSet<string>();
        APPROVED_USING_STATEMENTS.Add("System.Text");
        APPROVED_USING_STATEMENTS.Add("System.Data");
        APPROVED_USING_STATEMENTS.Add("System.Text.RegularExpressions");
        APPROVED_USING_STATEMENTS.Add("System");
        APPROVED_USING_STATEMENTS.Add("System.Linq");
        APPROVED_USING_STATEMENTS.Add("System.Collections");
        APPROVED_USING_STATEMENTS.Add("System.Security.Cryptography");
        APPROVED_USING_STATEMENTS.Add("Project.ProjectB");
```

The compiler code is as follows:

```
                foreach (var apprvUsingStatements in DataTransformationScript.GetApprovedUsingStatements())
                {
                    usingStatements.Append("using " + apprvUsingStatements + "; \n");
                }
               
                string transformCode = usingStatements.ToString();
                transformCode += "object returnObject = currentData;";
                transformCode += schemaMap.transform_script;
                transformCode += ";returnObject";
                ScriptOptions references = ScriptOptions.Default.AddReferences(DataTransformationScript.GetApprovedUsingStatements());
                //Adding my own personal references from Connector
                var asm = typeof(Project.ProjectB.TestTransformation).Assembly;
                references.AddReferences(asm);
                //HTMLEncodeLogMessage.Info(Logger, "Assmebly added: " + asm.FullName + " Location " + asm.Location + " Given Name " + asm.GetName().Name);
                //===============================================//
                var transformScript = CSharpScript.Create(transformCode, references, globalsType: typeof(DataTransformationScript.Globals));
                transformScript.Compile();
```

As you can see, I add the reference to Project B using the following code extract:

```
            var asm = typeof(Project.ProjectB.TestTransformation).Assembly;
            references.AddReferences(asm);
```

And I already have the using statement above for project as "using Project.ProjectB". (TestTransformation is just a method inside ProjectB. It seems I had to use the method name as well to get the reference dll.

I am still getting an error: The type or namespace name 'Project' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

Am I missing any other kind of reference that I need to add? I noticed I am not getting this error for all the "System" references that I have. Is it possible that C# Script objects only get data from the folders inside C:\Windows\assembly?

I have looked at the following stackoverflow question and it DID NOT solve my problem:
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38277781/how-to-add-and-use-an-import-in-a-script)

I would really appreciate any kind of guidance and assistance. I am still learning.

Comment: based on my test, I didn't meet the error. If the code   transformScript.Compile(); works nornally, what will happened for the program?

Comment: I run the following command: ScriptValidator scriptValidator = new ScriptValidator(transformScript); after I compiled the code and I got the error: The type or namespace name 'Project' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

Answer (score 0):

Try using costura fody/ fody library